# Why this message: does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument

Tags: c#

**Hi,**

What I'm doing is a method to display images from a specific folder but when I debug I'm getting this error on the last line of code and I have no idea why.**

```
Error 3 'MBKiosk.classTools' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension    
method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'MBKiosk.classTools' could be found (are you 
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**Thanks for any help.**

**Here is the code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using MBKiosk;

namespace MBKiosk
{
    class classTools
    {
        public void ShowImages(string path)
        {
            FlowLayoutPanel imagePanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            imagPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            imagePanel.Size = new Size(1240, 630);
            imagePanel.Location = new Point(12, 344);
            imagePanel.WrapContents = true;
            imagePanel.AutoScroll = false;
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            foreach (FileInfo file in dInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(file.Extension);
                if ((file.Extension == ".jpg") || (file.Extension == ".gif") || (file.Extension == 
                    ".png"))
                {
                    PictureBox image = new PictureBox();
                    image.Image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName);
                    image.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
                    image.Size = new Size(180, 108);
                    imagePanel.Controls.Add(image);
                    imagePanel.Refresh();
                }
            }
            this.Controls.Add(imagePanel);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's an accurate message, you didn't provide a Controls member.  Maybe you meant `class classTools : Form {}` so you'd inherit the members of the Form class?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you copy and paste code.  this.Controls expects your class 'classTools' to have a member Controls.  Either add the intended member variable to 'classTools' or derive it from another class.

Comment: Is this an answer or did you really mean to ask 3 questions?  Use a comment for that.

Comment: I believe it gives him enough information to solve the problem.  Something I'm missing?

Comment: Probably.  An answer doesn't use question marks.  Socrates died 2411 years ago.

Comment: Noted.  And my condolences to Mrs. Socrates.

Answer (score 0):

You imported `System.Windows.Forms` but are not actually using it. Change you class definition to `class classTools : Forms`, and then you will be able to use the [`Controls` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx).

And seems like [there is no `Add` method in the `Controls` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control_methods(v=vs.110).aspx), as long as you don't add the `Add` extension method to `Controls`, it is going to give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was copy/pasting the user controls for an other page, but I havn't checked the `src` at the `Register` tag on top of the page.
It appears it didn't started at the root (`~/`), so it could only find files that were on the same map:

```
<%@ Register Src="MyPopUp.ascx" TagName="MyPopup" TagPrefix="uc3" %>
```

Due to this, it saw it as an UserControl rather than it's own class.

The page I copied the control to was on a different map, so correcting that path, and starting from the root have fixed the issue.